# springdoc-openapi: spring gateway: gateway api endpoints are not showing

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-gateway, springdoc-openapi-ui

Not able to get the gateway url's neither in JSON or swagger UI.
Below is the configuration.
Could any one suggest on this

**Spring configuration:**

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: testapi
          uri: "localhost:8090/api/test/v1"
          predicates:
            - Path=/sa
          filters:
            - AddRequestHeader=secure,true
  application:
    name: gateway-service
server:
  port: 8080
springdoc:
  api-docs:
    path: /api-docs

URL: localhost:8080/api-docs
**Respose:** 
{
    "openapi": "3.0.1",
    "info": {
        "title": "OpenAPI definition",
        "version": "v0"
    },
    "servers": [
        {
            "url": "http://localhost:8080",
            "description": "Generated server url"
        }
    ],
    "paths": {},
    "components": {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to enable endpoint support

```
springdoc.show-actuator=true
```

and

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=gateway
```

Note that you are using a yml file, please convert the above code to yml format